# Deploy multiple angular apps on single VPS through nginx

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, nginx, gulp

I have two web apps bootstrapped from https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular.
I want to deploy one app at http://myvps.com/app1 and other at http://myvps.com/app2.

Here is the nginx configuration that I am using for this purpose

```
location /app1 {
  proxy_pass http://myvps.com:3000;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  rewrite ^/app1/(.*)$ /$1 break;
 }
location /app2 {
  proxy_pass http://myvps.com:5000;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  rewrite ^/app2/(.*)$ /$1 break;
  }
```

I don't want to serve static content from nginx, everything should be served from nodejs server.
I have also added

```
<base href="/app1/">
```

and

```
<base href="/app2/">
```

but nothing seems to work, all the static resources give 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, I found the answer after spending a day to get it work, and since no one has answered this yet I thought I'd post my solution.
I had to serve from `dist` not from `src`, so for this purpose I had to do `gulp serve:dist`.

I did not had to change anything else like nginx configuration, or anything else. Hope it helps anyone else.